# My JscrollPane isn't scrolling (vertically) the entire image,

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, preferredsize

when I increase the preferredSize, more of the Bufferedimage(on a JPanel, on a JFrame) is found.

The size of the image is going to vary depending on the size of the file my program is reading,

where I set the scrollpane;

```
public Frame(String title, int theWidth, int theHeight) throws FileNotFoundException {

        super(String.format("Title", title));
        this.width = theWidth;
        this.height = theHeight;
        this.panel = new Panel(width, height);
        this.scroller = new JScrollPane(this.panel);
        this.panel.drawLinesAndTab();
        this.scroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        this.scroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        this.scroller.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(this.width, this.height));
        this.getContentPane().add(this.scroller);
    }
```

And (don't shoot me), this is my Panel class;

```
public class Panel extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage image;
    private ReadTabFile tab;
    private String title;
    private String theNotes;
    private String theFlag;
    private int a, b, c, x, y, beginBarlineX, beginBarlineY, endBarX, endBarY;
    private ArrayList list;
    private Font letterFont;
    private Font flagFont;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    boolean newLine = false;

    public Panel(int theWidth, int theHeight) throws FileNotFoundException {

        this.width = theWidth;
        this.height = theHeight;
        this.tab = new ReadTabFile("tabSource.txt");
        this.image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics g = this.image.createGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, this.image.getWidth(), this.image.getHeight());
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        this.setFocusable(true);

    }

    public void drawLinesAndTab() {

        Graphics g = this.image.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        this.list = tab.readTabCode();
        this.a = 20;
        this.b = 100;
        this.c = 60;
        this.x = 40;
        this.y = 100;
        this.beginBarlineX = 20;
        this.beginBarlineY = 100;
        this.endBarY = 980;
        this.endBarY = 100;
        this.title = tab.getTitle();
        g.drawString(this.title, 40, 20);

        for (int i = 0; i < this.list.size(); i++) {
            Bar theBar = (Bar) this.list.get(i);
            drawBarline(a, b, a, b + 125);
            ArrayList<String> stuff = theBar.getLinesInBar();

            for (int j = 0; j < stuff.size(); j++) {
                String line = stuff.get(j);
                theFlag = line.substring(0, 1);
                theNotes = line.substring(1, line.length());
                if (newLine = true){
                    //make some bar lines.
                }

                try {

                    int w = this.image.getWidth();
                    //int h = this.image.getHeight();

                    if (c <= (w - 40)) {

                        newLine = false;
                        String zero = theFlag;
                        drawFlag(zero, x + 5, y - 20);

                        String one = theNotes.substring(0, 1);
                        g.drawLine(a, b, c, b);
                        drawLetter(one, x, y);

                        String two = theNotes.substring(1, 2);
                        drawLetter(two, x, y += 25);
                        g.drawLine(a, b += 25, c, b);

                        String three = theNotes.substring(2, 3);
                        drawLetter(three, x, y += 25);
                        g.drawLine(a, b += 25, c, b);

                        String four = theNotes.substring(3, 4);
                        drawLetter(four, x, y += 25);
                        g.drawLine(a, b += 25, c, b);

                        String five = theNotes.substring(4, 5);
                        drawLetter(five, x, y += 25);
                        g.drawLine(a, b += 25, c, b);

                        String six = theNotes.substring(5, 6);
                        drawLetter(six, x, y += 25);
                        g.drawLine(a, b += 25, c, b);
                        this.repaint();

                        b -= 125;
                        y -= 125;
                        x += 40;
                        a += 40;
                        c += 40;

                    } else {
                        newLine = true;
                        a = 20;
                        x = 20;
                        b += 225;
                        c = 60;
                        y += 225;
                        beginBarlineX = 20;
                        beginBarlineY += 100;
                        endBarX += 100;
                        endBarY = 100;
                        this.repaint();
                    }

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.err.println(ex + " within Panel, drawtab for loop");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void drawBarline(int xTop, int yTop, int xBot, int yBot) {
        Graphics g = this.image.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawLine(xTop, yTop, xBot, yBot);

    }

    public Point makeBarline(int xTop, int yTop, int xBot, int yBot) {
        Graphics g = this.image.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawLine(xTop, yTop, xBot, yBot);
        return (new Point());
    }

    public Point drawLetter(String letter, int x, int y) throws FontFormatException, IOException {

        Graphics g = this.image.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.setFont(letterFont(letter).deriveFont(20.0f));
        g.drawString(letter, x, y);

        return (new Point());
    }

    public Point drawFlag(String letter, int x, int y) throws FontFormatException, IOException {

        Graphics g = this.image.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.setFont(flagFont(letter).deriveFont(30.0f));
        g.drawString(letter, x, y);

        return (new Point());
    }

    public Font letterFont(String fontString) throws FontFormatException, IOException {

        Graphics g = this.image.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.black);

        if (!Character.isDigit(fontString.charAt(0))) {
            this.letterFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("LeRoy.ttf"));
            g.getFontMetrics(this.letterFont);
            g.setFont(this.letterFont);
            return this.letterFont;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public Font flagFont(String fontString) throws FontFormatException, IOException {

        Graphics g = this.image.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.black);

        if (!Character.isDigit(fontString.charAt(0))) {
            this.flagFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("LeroyLuteNotes1.ttf"));
            g.getFontMetrics(this.flagFont);
            g.setFont(this.flagFont);
            return this.flagFont;
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return (new Dimension(this.image.getWidth(), this.image.getHeight()));
    }

    public BufferedImage getImage() {
        return this.image;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {

        Graphics g = graphics.create();
        g.drawImage(this.image, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

I think I've set it up correctly, I've not used a layout manager because all I'm doing is basically writing lines and text to the image/panel. It is working fine, but I need to be able to scroll right down to the bottom of the image.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `JScrollPane` respects component preferred size to set it's content view, not the component's content.
2. If you wish to scroll with respect to content: image, Override `getPreferreedSize(Dimension)` function of the `Panel` class and return the image size as the component's preferred size.
3. We should always  call `super.paintComponent(g)` inside the overriden `paintComponent(Graphics)` function, which you are not doing for now.

Comment: I think I was already overriding the getPreferredSize(D) in my Panel class, A Dimension takes two ints right? which I passed as this.image.getWidth() and this.image.getHeight(). I also set the preferredSize in the Frame class. So I'm still puzzled as to why it's not scrolling to the bottom.

Comment: @juju, Try by not setting preferred size to `JScrollPane` as you are adding it to frame content pane with `add(scrollPane)` which will add `JScrollPane` to the `BorderLayout.CENTER`. Rather just call `pack()` at the end of the `Frame()` constructor. Try it and let me know

Comment: thanks for your help, this.pack() seems to be doing exactly the same as getPreferredSize() so I'm thinking that its something else. There is now a null pointer being thrown out somewhere, so testing time.

Comment: The scroller is now working, thanks for your help. The image is still only showing at the size of the panel. But thank you for your help :)