# BufferedImage only showing on 1/3 of JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, bufferedimage

Here's my original [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20399492/my-jscrollpane-isnt-scrolling-vertically-the-entire-image) on SO kindly answered. The height is now set at what I think is the correct size. But I can't see the bottom 2/3s of the panel.

I have read, and asked, and mused, and experimented, but I still cannot find an answer. I don't need code, just a little help.

My JFrame class;

```
public Frame(String title) throws FileNotFoundException {

        super(String.format("Title", title));
        this.panel = new Panel();
        this.panel.drawLinesAndTab();
        this.panel.setSize(this.panel.getPreferredSize());
        this.panel.validate();
        this.scroller = new JScrollPane(this.panel);
        //this.scroller.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(this.panel.getPreferredSize()));
        this.scroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        this.scroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        //this.scroller.setSize(new Dimension(this.panel.getPreferredSize()));
        this.scroller.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(20);
        this.getContentPane().add(this.scroller);
        //this.pack();
    }
```

and this is the JPanel class. I know it's huge, and I do have plans to re-write this code, but I'm under time limitations and have to try and get it at least seeing all of the output.

```
 public Panel() throws FileNotFoundException {

        this.tab = new ReadTabFile("tabSource.txt");
        this.image = new BufferedImage(this.width, this.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics g = this.image.createGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, this.image.getWidth(), this.image.getHeight());
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        this.setFocusable(true);

    }

    public void drawLinesAndTab() {

        Graphics g = this.image.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        this.list = tab.readTabCode();
        this.a = 20;
        this.b = 100;
        this.c = 60;
        this.x = 40;
        this.y = 100;
        this.beginBarlineX = 20;
        this.beginBarlineY = 100;
        this.endBarY = 980;
        this.endBarY = 100;
        this.title = tab.getTitle();
        g.drawString(this.title, 40, 20);

        for (int i = 0; i < this.list.size(); i++) {
            Bar theBar = (Bar) this.list.get(i);
            drawBarline(a, b, a, b + 125);
            ArrayList<String> stuff = theBar.getLinesInBar();

            for (int j = 0; j < stuff.size(); j++) {
                String line = stuff.get(j);
                theFlag = line.substring(0, 1);
                theNotes = line.substring(1, line.length());
                if (newLine = true) {
                }
                try {

                    System.out.println(theNotes);

                    if (c <= (width - 40)) {

                        newLine = false;
                        String zero = theFlag;
                        drawFlag(zero, x + 5, y - 20);

                        String one = theNotes.substring(0, 1);
                        g.drawLine(a, b, c, b);
                        drawLetter(one, x, y);

                        String two = theNotes.substring(1, 2);
                        drawLetter(two, x, y += 25);
                        g.drawLine(a, b += 25, c, b);

                        String three = theNotes.substring(2, 3);
                        drawLetter(three, x, y += 25);
                        g.drawLine(a, b += 25, c, b);

                        String four = theNotes.substring(3, 4);
                        drawLetter(four, x, y += 25);
                        g.drawLine(a, b += 25, c, b);

                        String five = theNotes.substring(4, 5);
                        drawLetter(five, x, y += 25);
                        g.drawLine(a, b += 25, c, b);

                        String six = theNotes.substring(5, 6);
                        drawLetter(six, x, y += 25);
                        g.drawLine(a, b += 25, c, b);
                        this.repaint();

                        b -= 125;
                        y -= 125;
                        x += 40;
                        a += 40;
                        c += 40;

                    } else {
                        if (height < (b - 100)) {
                            height += 205;

                        }
                        newLine = true;
                        a = 20;
                        x = 20;
                        b += 225;
                        c = 60;
                        y += 225;
                        beginBarlineX = 20;
                        beginBarlineY += 100;
                        endBarX += 100;
                        endBarY = 100;
                        this.repaint();
                    }

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.err.println(ex + " within if drawtab/line for loop");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void drawBarline(int xTop, int yTop, int xBot, int yBot) {
        Graphics g = this.image.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawLine(xTop, yTop, xBot, yBot);

    }

    public Point makeBarline(int xTop, int yTop, int xBot, int yBot) {
        Graphics g = this.image.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawLine(xTop, yTop, xBot, yBot);
        return (new Point());
    }

    public Point drawLetter(String letter, int x, int y) throws FontFormatException, IOException {

        Graphics g = this.image.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.setFont(letterFont(letter).deriveFont(20.0f));
        g.drawString(letter, x, y);

        return (new Point());
    }

    public Point drawFlag(String letter, int x, int y) throws FontFormatException, IOException {

        Graphics g = this.image.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.setFont(flagFont(letter).deriveFont(30.0f));
        g.drawString(letter, x, y);

        return (new Point());
    }

    public Font letterFont(String fontString) throws FontFormatException, IOException {

        Graphics g = this.image.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.black);

        if (!Character.isDigit(fontString.charAt(0))) {
            this.letterFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("LeRoy.ttf"));
            g.getFontMetrics(this.letterFont);
            g.setFont(this.letterFont);
            return this.letterFont;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public Font flagFont(String fontString) throws FontFormatException, IOException {

        Graphics g = this.image.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.black);

        if (!Character.isDigit(fontString.charAt(0))) {
            this.flagFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("LeroyLuteNotes1.ttf"));
            g.getFontMetrics(this.flagFont);
            g.setFont(this.flagFont);
            return this.flagFont;
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return (new Dimension(this.width, this.height));
    }

    public BufferedImage getImage() {
        return this.image;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {

        super.paintComponent(graphics);
        Graphics g = graphics.create();
        g.drawImage(this.image, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm adding to the height during the workings of the panel class, I'm not 100% sure I can do this, but it does seem to be half working.

Comment: Sorry, but you need a lot of help.  This is nothing like how Swing should be coded.  Read this [Hangman Swing GUI](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=349) article to see how a Swing GUI is constructed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are attempting to do with that code. It looks like you might be trying to do some custom painting on top of an image. If so then I have the following suggestions:

```
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return (new Dimension(this.width, this.height));
}
```

This makes no sense, you are saying that the preferred size is equal to the actual size of the component. The preferred size should be the size of the image.

Your custom painting code is completely wrong. All custom painting code should be done from the paintComponent() method. So first you would paint the image as the background of your component. Then you would invoke the other painting methods to paint stuff on top of the image. You would pass the Graphics object from the paintComponent() method to all of these other painting methods, instead of using image.getGraphics().

Start with a simple custom painting example from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html). Once you learn the basics you customize your code one step at a time. That is first paint the background. Make sure the size is correct and scrolling works. Then move to the next step and add another method to paint something else on top of the image.

I never understand why people write hundreds of lines of code without doing basic testing along the way to make sure the code is working.

Comment: I have been testing the code, and the program works. It has worked from the beginning. 

"This makes no sense, you are saying that the preferred size is equal to the actual size of the component. The preferred size should be the size of the image."

this.width and this.height are set in the constructor as the being the size of the image, and are changed throughout the drawLinesAndTab() method. I didn't know if this was possible. Having now read the custom painting tutorial I realize that my system should be set up differently, but I do not have the time to change it now.

Comment: so there is no way to display the whole image?

Comment: `I do not have the time to change it now.` - you have been having problems for two days. Maybe if you do it the proper way the problems will disappear. `there is no way to display the whole image?` - I already told you how to do this.