# Once I've set the bounds of a BufferedImage, is it possible to change it?

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I have been asking about this quite a lot, and have posted on SO before about my [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20445298/bufferedimage-only-showing-on-1-3-of-jpanel), the system is now set up properly (@camickr, @Gilbert Le Blanc - I thank you for your frank advice, it helped a lot) and my methods are being appropriately called from the paintComponent.

I basically want to know if I can resize the boundry of the BufferedImage as I read a text file. So that the height would be increased incrementally. Not increase the size of what's already visible.

Any advice would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I know of, but you could make one that is huge and then refer to a portion of it though a subimage, as a hacky workaround. "resizing" would then mean defining a new subimage only. Check out BufferedImage.getSubimage() in the API docs.

But it is easier to just construct a new one and then paint the original to the new one, much like you would do when resizing an array. I don't know the exact details of your application (such as how often you would resize) so I can't say if any of what I've suggested would have acceptable performance or not.

Yet another alternative is to not use a BufferedImage directly but rather your own data object to store the pixel data, which you would then in the end transform into a BufferedImage once.

Comment: fantastic, these are fantastic suggestions. Thank you. I have already gone for the hacky quick fix for now (not ideal), but this is an ongoing project so I will definitly look into the above.